# Get apt's key ids and fingerprints in machine-readable format

Tags: apt, gpg

I'm trying to patch an issue in puppetlabs-apt to enable the use of key fingerprints as identifiers to ensure that a certain key is present by its 40-digit key fingerprint.

I'm having difficulty checking that the key is present and I need a command which will output the following:

- The 8-digit ID of the key.
- The 16-digit ID of the key.
- The 40-digit ID of the key.

Is there an `apt-key` command I can use to output these values, one per line, so I can parse the output and check if the key is present?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

`apt-key adv` will let you directly pass options to GnuPG.

So you can do something like this to get parseable outpout:

```
# apt-key adv --list-public-keys --with-fingerprint --with-colons 
⋮
fpr:::::::::126C0D24BD8A2942CC7DF8AC7638D0442B90D010:
pub:-:4096:1:9D6D8F6BC857C906:2014-11-21:2022-11-19::-:Debian Security Archive Automatic Signing Key (8/jessie) <ftpmaster@debian.org>::scSC:
fpr:::::::::D21169141CECD440F2EB8DDA9D6D8F6BC857C906:
⋮
```

Since you're only interested in the fingerprint (the 8-digit and 16-digit IDs are just the end of the fingerprint), `| grep ^fpr` would seem to give you the lines you care about.

Comment: So taking `fingerprint[-8:]` (Python) would get me the 8-digit ID and `fingerpint[-16:]` would get me the 16-digit ID? Silly me for thinking that these were cryptologically derived short-hashes...

Comment: @NaftuliTzviKay The fingerprint is a cryptographically derived hash. There isn't any security benefit to hashing it again vs. just truncating it. Further the 8-digit and probably 16-digit ones are too short to be secure; you can generate a duplicate key by brute force. Only the full hash is reasonably secure. Can't comment if your python code does as expected, as I don't know python... But I'd guess yes. It's just the last 8 or 16 hex digits.

Comment: this appears to remove important information, like if key is expired. This is dealbreaking considering that apt-key cannot filter expired keys